# Definition of a Website (not from wiki)

Tags: website-design

For example, I have 3 different websites but they are all under the same organization.
1. www.website1.com
2. www.website2.com
3. www.website3.com
4. Parent company: www.parentwebsite.com

However, my client wants to port over all these sub-websites under the parent domain to help save hosting costs:
www.parentwebsite.com/website1
www.parentwebsite.com/website2
www.parentwebsite.com/website3

I'm wondering if they do it this way, will it affect their users' attitude towards a certain branding.

When I showed the homepage for www.parentwebsite.com to others, they mentioned that this is a website. However, when I showed the homepage for www.parentwebsite.com/website1 to others, they told me that this is not a website, but it's just a webpage within a website.

Then my question would be, what is the real definition of a website? Is www.parentwebsite.com/website1 considered a website or a webpage, or there is no difference?

Comment: I would answer: use sub domains, such as "website1.parentwebsite.com" etc.. Good luck!

Comment: You should talk to my wife.  I tried putting together a site for her business.  She exclaimed, "that is NOT a website"...  Many hours later I finally figured out that she meant the colors were wrong.

Answer (score 2):

There is no "official" definition of a website, and no official body determining what the word means.

However, in general use, a webpage is a single page on a website, and a website is made of a collection of pages that form a volume (usually on a single domain).

Think of a book as an analogy, where you can think of a book as a website, and a page in that book as a webpage.  Yes, you may start off on the index page of the book, but that doesn't make the index page a book.  It's still a page.  It's one of the reasons that the default page for a site is often called a "landing page".